# Update the Web-Front-End of a Google Kubernetes Engine Webapplication

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, web-frontend

i used this https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/guestbook?hl=de to bulid a Guestbook with Google Kubernetes Engine.
I applyed this an everything works.
Now i wanted to change the index.html for a better Look.
How can i upload or update the changed file?

I tried to apply the frontend service again with this
`kubectl apply -f frontend-service.yaml`
But it did not work.

Comment: get the code build docker again and upload to the container registry and update yaml file and apply.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to rebuild the containers if you make changes to the source code. I suggest you:

- Download docker and run docker build to rebuild the containers locally.
- Push the containers to your own Artifact Registry(AR) following this guide https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/pushing-and-pulling.
- Update the yaml files to point to your own AR.
- Redeploy the application to GKE